# Separate counters using closure

Tags: javascript

Given the following code, how would you make each button add 1 to its respective counter.  Currently when a button is pressed it adds 1 to its counter, but when the other button is pressed it adds the sum of the other counter plus 1. I know this can be done by creating another *add* variable, but is it possible to do this without creating another counter function?

```html
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Count!</button>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction2()">Count!</button>
<p id="demo">0</p>
<p id="demo2">0</p>
<script>
var add = (function () {
    var counter = 0;
    return function () {return counter += 1;}
})();

function myFunction(){
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = add();
}

function myFunction2(){
    document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = add();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following, note the added id to the button to make things simple

```
<button type="button" id="btn1">Count!</button>
<button type="button" id="btn2">Count!</button>
<p id="demo">0</p>
<p id="demo2">0</p>
<script>
function counter(b, p) {
  var button = document.getElementById(b);
  var para = document.getElementById(p);
  var value = 0;
  button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    para.innerHTML = value += 1;
  });
}
counter('btn1', 'demo');
counter('btn2', 'demo2');
</script>
```

Each call to counter creates a closure for the click event to update the correct `<p>`

Even simpler, you don't need to create a var to hold the value as the value is held in the element itself

```
<button type="button" id="btn1">Count!</button>
<button type="button" id="btn2">Count!</button>
<p id="demo">0</p>
<p id="demo2">0</p>
<script>
function counter(b, p) {
  var para = document.getElementById(p);
  document.getElementById(b).addEventListener('click', function() {
    para.innerHTML = parseInt(para.innerHTML) + 1;
  });
}
counter('btn1', 'demo');
counter('btn2', 'demo2');
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider creating a separate counter as follows without having to duplicate the `add` logic.

```html
<button type="button" onclick="count1()">Count!</button>
<button type="button" onclick="count2()">Count!</button>
<p id="demo">0</p>
<p id="demo2">0</p>
<script>
  function createCounter() {
    var counter = 0;
    return function () { return ++counter; }
  }

  var counter1 = createCounter();
  var counter2 = createCounter();

  function count1() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = counter1();
  }

  function count2() {
    document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = counter2();
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may also try this :

```
function counter(start) {
    return function increment(){
        start += 1;
        return start;
    }
}

function onButtonClick(sourceElemId, counterFunc){
    document.getElementById(sourceElemId).innerHTML = counterFunc();
}
```

In HTML:

```
<button type="button" 
       onclick="onButtonClick('demo', counter(0))">Count!
 </button>
<button type="button" 
        onclick="onButtonClick('demo2', counter(0))">Count!</button>
<p id="demo">0</p>
<p id="demo2">0</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var counter1 = 0;
var counter2 = 0;
var add = function (count) {
    return count += 1;
};

function myFunction(){
    counter1 = add(counter1)
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = counter1;
}

function myFunction2(){
    counter2 = add(counter2)
    document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = counter2;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Count!</button>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction2()">Count!</button>
<p id="demo">0</p>
<p id="demo2">0</p>
```

You were redefining counter to be 0 every time you called `add`.  In addition, since you want two different counters, you need two different variables to keep track of each.  And honestly you could probably eliminate the `add` function and just add to each counter within its specific function with `counterX = counterX++` instead of `counterX = add(counterX)`